# Java stream sorting elements of List<Object>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am currently trying to learn streams in Java, however I stumbled upon a problem I couldn't solve on my own. Given a List of `Person` objects with the attributes age, height and name. I want to write a method `toString()`, that sorts the List by height and in case the heights are equal by age (everything in descending order). Is there a possibility to solve this with a stream? I know how to sort the List by height, however I don't understand how you would get the equal elements (Persons with the same height) and sort them as well by age.

Class `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private double height;
    private String name;

    public Person(int age, double height, String name){
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The Data class (where you create the toString method):

```
public class Data {
    private List<Person> persons;

    public Data(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public String toString(){
        //sort the list (persons) and return a String of names

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Comparator chaining to sort by height and then by age. Then use the `map` operator to map the names and finally joining collector to concatenate the names into a formatted string of your interest. Here's how it looks.

```
String sortedNames = persons.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getHeight)
        .thenComparingDouble(Person::getAge).reversed())
    .map(Person::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

P.S. However, I don't see `double` as a good data type to represent the age of a person. An int would be a much better alternative IMO.

**Update:**

If you have `int` data type to represent the age of a person, then the comparator chain should look like below. Everything else remains intact.

```
Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getHeight)
        .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. I just wrote the Person class and of course the age should be an Integer.

Comment: If you can update the question, then I can update my answer too.

Comment: Good catch. Let me update the answer accordingly. Regarding height, it depends on the unit of measurement used. For an instance, if you are using meters, then it can be a `double` value. Like 1.78 m height.

Comment: In that case, you have to use a`BigDecimal` type.